# Why aren't components inside VerticalLayout aligned vertically in Vaadin 11?

Tags: java, layout, vaadin

I have a view in Vaadin 11, which is displayed at URL like `products/X` where `X` is a product identifier.

```
@Route(value = "products")
public class ProductView extends VerticalLayout implements HasUrlParameter<String> {

    public ProductView() {

    }

    [...]
}
```

I cannot display any information on this page without having a product, therefore I add all components in the method `setParameter`:

```
@Override
public void setParameter(final BeforeEvent beforeEvent, 
                final String param) {
    final Product product = findProduct(param);

    if (product == null) {
        return;
    }
    final Text name = new Text(product.getName());
    final Text interestRate = new Text(String.format("Ставка: %.2f", 
                    product.getInterestRatePercentPerAnnum()));
    final Text duration = new Text(String.format("Срок: %d - %d месяцев",
                    product.getDurationMonths().getStart(),
                    product.getDurationMonths().getEndInclusive()));
    final Text provider = new Text(String.format("Организация: %s",
                    product.getProvider().getName()));
    final Text description = new Text("<html>Hi there! <b>Bold</b> text</html>");


    add(name);
    add(interestRate);
    add(duration);
    add(description);
    add(provider);
}
```

But the various data items are displayd in one line:

[image: Screenshot]

This means that for some reason `VerticalLayout` layous out the components horizontally.

How can I fix it (make sure that each component that I add is displayed on a separate line)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Text` is a specific component, since it corresponds to text nodes in the DOM (in the browser). Therefore, there are no HTML elements and the content added to the `VerticalLayout` will flow from left to right. That's how it looks in the browser tree:
[image]

Use `Div` instead:

```
final Div name = new Div(new Text("Product"));
final Div interestRate = new Div(new Text(String.format("Ставка: %.2f",
            0.05d)));
final Div duration = new Div(new Text(String.format("Срок: %d - %d "
            + "месяцев", 10, 11)));
final Div provider = new Div(new Text(String.format("Организация: %s"
            , 10)));
final Div description = new Div(new Text("<html>Hi there! <b>Bold</b>"
            + " text</html>"));
```

By using `Div`, you're inserting `div` elements into the `VerticalLayout` so it can do it's work.